# Powershell Remote DIR/findstr command exclude tempory internet folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this command through powershell, on remote machines

dir C:\Users\ /S/B | findstr /i "t.st" > C:\results.txt

But I want to exclude the temporary internet files folders, as it is giving me a lot of false positives

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (updated):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Recurse | `
   Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch 'Temporary Internet Files' -and $_.FullName -like '*t.st*'} | `
   Foreach-Object {$_.FullName} | `
   Out-File C:\results.txt
```

Comment: Will try and see how fast that is in comparison to dir. I know I tried WMI thru VB scripting

Comment: I get this error "Unexpected token '-not' in expression or statement"

Comment: I updated my answer, give it another try (it's not using the -not operator)

Comment: Does this script still traverse the Temporary Internet Files directory and sub-directories? I want to do a similar thing but for performance reasons I don't want the script to check each and every sub-directory file (in this example within the Temp Internet Files), rather than simply filter out the results.

Comment: Yes, if -Recurse is present it will drill down all the way.